# Twitter API not returning all followers, even with cursoring and avoiding rate limiting

Tags: api, twitter

I'm using the Twitter API to get all followers for particular accounts. This works, but consistently returns fewer followers than Twitter reports as the total number of followers.

I properly avoid rate limiting by not issuing more than 15 requests per 15 minutes on the `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json` endpoint. And I use cursoring.

Here's an idea of what I get vs what the total number reported is.

Account 1: Followers returned by the API: 604, Number of followers reported on profile's page: 619

Account 2: 48000, 125K

Account 3: 250200, 1.16M

Why are not all followers returned?

Comment: Another way to get a lot of followers or friends is : first, get followers IDs (pages of 5000 max) with https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/api-reference-index . Then to get user screen names, lookup those IDs : https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-lookup

Comment: Thanks @JeffProd. I am considering trying that. But that does not explain the discrepancy I encounter above.